# Vietnamese passport validity for early renewal

Tags: vietnamese-citizens

I have a Vietnamese passport which will expire on August 2018 and I plan to renew it in July 2017 due to visa expiration on August 2017. My question is will the remaining validity on my old passport added to my new passport, which means that my new passport will have the expiration date of August 2028?

Answer (score 2):

No, your new passport will expire in Aug 2027

According to Nghị định 94/2015/NĐ-CP:

> Điều 1. Sửa đổi, bổ sung một số điều của Nghị định số 136/2007/NĐ-CP
>
> 1. Khoản 2 Điều 4 về thời hạn của các loại giấy tờ có giá trị xuất cảnh, nhập cảnh được sửa đổi, bổ sung như sau:
>
> a) Sửa đổi, bổ sung điểm a, Khoản 2 như sau:
>
> "a) Hộ chiếu quốc gia:
>
> - Hộ chiếu ngoại giao, hộ chiếu công vụ có giá trị không quá 5 năm tính từ ngày cấp. Hộ chiếu ngoại giao, hộ chiếu công vụ còn giá trị
>     dưới 1 năm thì được gia hạn một lần, tối đa không quá 3 năm; khi hết
>     hạn thì làm thủ tục cấp mới.
> - Hộ chiếu phổ thông có giá trị không quá 10 năm tính từ ngày cấp và không được gia hạn. Hộ chiếu phổ thông còn hạn thì được cấp lại, khi
>     hết hạn thì làm thủ tục cấp mới.